# Bash doesn't display the result of nested if-else statements

Tags: bash, if-statement, nested

I'm trying to nest a couple of if/else statements. Maybe I'm making a very silly mistake but I can't get it to work. There are 3 variables in order, one of them at random will be "-1".

If one of them is "-1", then all the following ones are "-1" as well, so if FOO2 is "-1", then FOO3 is as well.

I need to print to the console whenever a variable is "-1", prioritizing the first one, so the last example should only print "FOO2 is -1" and nothing else.

This should print "FOO3 is -1", but it doesn't.

```
FOO1="2"
FOO2="2"
FOO3="-1"

if [ ${FOO1} -eq "-1" ]
then
    if [ ${FOO2} -eq "-1" ]
    then
        if [ ${FOO3} -eq "-1" ]
        then
            echo "FOO3 is -1"
        else 
            echo "FOO2 is -1"
        fi
    else 
        echo "FOO1 is -1"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Hint: Try running `bash -x yourscript` to see what it actually executes.

Comment: ...that's already been done for you at https://ideone.com/im2UG1. Because `[ ${FOO1} -eq "-1" ]` is false, and all your other code is in the `then` clause (it has no `else` clause at all!), none of that code ever gets run.

Comment: BTW, you're quoting exactly the wrong thing. There's no reason to quote `"-1"` in `[ ${FOO1} -eq "-1" ]`, but you *should* be quoting `"${FOO1}"` to stop it from being string-split and glob-expanded while generating the list of arguments to pass to the `[` command (`/usr/bin/[`, by the way, is also `/usr/bin/test`; both those executables and their shell-builtin equivalents that bash provides as a performance optimization comply with the specification at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: (While we're kibitzing here, btw -- all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell or operating system, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use; see the relevant specification at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace -- setting the former will overwrite the latter in a collision, so the same conventions apply to both).

Comment: (There's also no particular reason here to prefer `"${foo}"` over just `"$foo"`; in cases where there's no concatenation with a constant or parameterized expansion going on, the two are entirely equivalent; whereas unlike the curly braces, using quotes or failing to do so has very real correctness impact).

Answer (score 2):

Your first test is false, and has no `else` clause, so nothing beyond that first test gets run.

A saner version of this logic might look more like:

```
FOO1="2"
FOO2="2"
FOO3="-1"

if [ "${FOO1}" -eq -1 ]; then
    echo "FOO1 is -1"
elif [ "${FOO2}" -eq -1 ]; then
    echo "FOO2 is -1"
elif [ "${FOO3}" -eq -1 ]; then
    echo "FOO3 is -1"
fi
```

...or, if you really want to keep the nesting for some reason:

```
FOO1="2"
FOO2="2"
FOO3="-1"

if [ "${FOO1}" -eq -1 ]; then
    echo "FOO1 is -1"
else
    if [ "${FOO2}" -eq -1 ]; then
        echo "FOO2 is -1"
    else
        if [ "${FOO3}" -eq -1 ]; then
            echo "FOO3 is -1"
        fi
    fi
fi
```